# STM32 Logic level high and low thresholds

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer

I am scratching my head to find what are the minimum voltage for registering a low digital signal and maximum voltage for registering a high digital signal when I configure GPIO pins of STM32 (I am using STM32L476) as Input Capture mode (I want to measure some frequencies).

No where in the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l476je.pdf) and the [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf) I can see this details.

I have a signal that suppose to be around 0.3V when low and 1.8V when high...So I want to know these thresholds to either use a schmitt trigger in my circuit or use some divider resitors to up or down convert the levels to match inputs of STM32.

Comment: What is your supply voltage? The logic levels depend on it.

Comment: @filo I power the chip with 3.3V

Comment: *"6.3.14 I/O port characteristics"* in the datasheet.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep...I was searching for "threshold" apparently that was not the right keyword

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logic levels are described in section 6.3.14. When your supply voltage is 3.3V then:

V_IL = 0.39 * Vcc - 0.06 = 1.23 V (table row "I/O input low level voltage except BOOT0". The maximum voltage that will be read as logical zero is 1.23V (+ read all footnotes).

V_IH = 0.49 * Vcc + 0.26 = 1.88 V (table row "I/O input high level voltage except BOOT0"). You need to supply at lest 1.88 V to make the pin read as logical one.

Your 1.8 V signal is below V_IH and above V_IL, which means that the result is unpredictable.

You have to be concerned with the **maximum** voltage read as zero (ie. not exceed it) and the **minimum** voltage read as one, not the other way around.

Comment: wow nice catch....did you use any specific keyword to find that section?

Comment: I used "Vih"...

Comment: Practice, practice, practice :) Every single digital IC datasheet provides those parameters :)

Comment: The information actually seems to be missing in the STM32F40xxx datasheet… There is a V_IH and V_IL but for specific IOs only. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf